# How to receive list of binaries from server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS app, I am trying to get a list of serialized objects from an HTTP              server.

Which Apple API should I choose to get the binary from server?
I have read about NSURLSession, NSURLConnection, and others, but not sure which one to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Both will do. NSURLSession is much more powerful tool than NSURLConnection. 
If your task is simple - use NSURLConnection. If you need all that fine features of NSURLSession - go for it.

There's a great tutorial on using NSURLSession [NSURLSession tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial). It also states diff between both tools

Also, take a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) framework - makes everything much easier